# ContentControl in datagrid with Style.Trigger disappearing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid with two columns. First column contains cells with a combobox with two possible values (KoSt, WBKZ). Depending on that value column2 should show a different contentcontrol (textbox, autocompletebox):

[image: values]

If i choose more than one time the same value in column one than all other controls in column2 which will match to that value will disappear (except the current row).
[image: missing content]
Why does all of the other content dissappear? :(

```xml
                <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridAccounting"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentAction.ACCOUNTING_COLLECTION, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- first column binded to a static list with two values (KoSt, WBKZ)-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Konten-Art">
            <!-- shows the value of column1-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding KONTEN_ART, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <!-- lets the user click an item in combobox -->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource AccountingTypeList}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding KONTEN_ART, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <!-- second column. Content disappear when selecting more than one time same value in column 1-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="content">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl>
                        <ContentControl.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                <Style.Triggers>

                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding KONTEN_ART}" Value="KoSt">
                                        <Setter Property="Content">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Text="Value1 was chosen"></toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding KONTEN_ART}" Value="WBKZ">
                                        <Setter Property="Content">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <TextBox Text="Value2 was chosen"></TextBox>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ContentControl.Style>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you show some of your view model? Also, could it be that there is no content appearing because none of your ```DataTrigger``` actually triggers, meaning nothing sets the ```Content``` of your ```ContentControl```?

Comment: I dont work with mvvm. The binding to `CurrentAction.ACCOUNTING_COLLECTION` is a generic collection with several attributes with getter, setter, raiseupdate-event. If i do a binding to one attribute of that collection like `<TextBox Text="{Binding KONTEN_NUMMER, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>` inside of the contentcontrol, the content is still changeable and saveable, but the controls still disappear.

Comment: Can you add the following setter in your ```Style.Setters```:
```<Setter Property="Content">
 <Setter.Value>
  <TextBlock Text="Default content."></TextBlock >
 </Setter.Value>
</Setter>```
just to check if it is a ```DataTrigger``` issue.

Comment: You mean i shall change the textbox to textblock inside of the datatrigger? That will run into the same error.. `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding KONTEN_ART}" Value="WBKZ"><Setter Property="Content"><Setter.Value><TextBlock Text="Test"></TextBlock> [...]`

Comment: Instead of setting content in the DataTrigger, set the ContentTemplate.

Comment: No outside the datatrigger. I want you to add a setter before your datatriggers. This way, if none of your datatrigger triggers, this setter will apply by default.

Comment: Thank you Corentin. I ve put the Setter outside of the Style.Triggers, because it was not acceptable inside. But it runs into the same error. `<Style TargetType="ContentControl"><Setter Property="Content">[...]</Setter><Style.Triggers>[...]` It displays an default-text on other values than the two possibilities, but it is also just once visible: https://imgur.com/a3aISxX.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting `Content` of `ContentControl` in the `DataTrigger`, set the `ContentTemplate` like below

```
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding KONTEN_ART}" Value="KoSt">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Text="Value1 was chosen"></toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding KONTEN_ART}" Value="WBKZ">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="Value2 was chosen"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
```

Comment: This will make the controls appear but the data is not stored in my collection. I had to bind the Trigger because otherwise  there was no control visible: `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding KONTEN_ART}" Value="WBKZ">`

Comment: You can change the trigger binding to <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding KONTEN_ART}" Value="WBKZ">

Comment: Yeah but it will not store the value in my model/collection

Comment: What value do you want to store in your collection?

Comment: The user entered values

Comment: You can bind the value you want to update in the textbox

Comment: Your solution makes all controls visible but the binding of the control inside of the contenttemplate doesn't work anymore: `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding KONTEN_ART}" Value="WBKZ"><Setter Property="ContentTemplate"><Setter.Value><DataTemplate><TextBox Text="{Binding KONTEN_NUMMER,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>[...]`. This will not change/access my model-property _KONTEN_NUMMER_

Comment: Ok maybe I will make a new topic for the binding-problem. Thank you very much for ur help, i will accept this as correct answer!

Comment: Sure meanwhile i'll get back to you regarding the binding issue